# Run Multiple Queries parallel in FastAPI using SQLAlchemy And Run 2 Functions in Parallel which are executing a query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, parallel-processing, fastapi

I have 2 situations in my code that are making my API response slow.

1st Situation: Independent queries running in an order

```
   cursor.query(Model).all()
   cursor.query(Model).all()
```

I want these to run parallely so that together they take less time.

2nd Situation: Functions being called multiple times but had to wait until the previous one is completed:

````
   def asynFunc():
      cursor.query(Model).all()

   response = []
   for i in range(10):
      res = asyncFunc()
      response.append(res)```

Is there any way where I can run my code in parallel.
````